# How to get process id of specific process name in linux?

Tags: linux, cron, redhat, pid

I want to get the process id of specific process name in linux. Please see below my partial program.

```
 processid = $(pidof testQA) 
 if processid > 0 then echo "nothing"
  else echo "Server down" | mail "test@domain.com"
```

crontab:

```
30 * * * * test.sh
```

How to get process id from process name in linux ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use pidof command check here http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof `ps aux | grep -i "name"`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) along with its `-f` option:

```
pgrep -f testQA
```

Answer (score 0):

You should config the $PATH in your cron config file.Otherwise,in cron,the default $OATH is /usr/bin:/bin,so your script can not find pidof.So you must add PATH in your cron configfile in /var/spool/cron.see the example /etc/crontab